# Upload new apk to play store success. But in play store does not display update button

Tags: android

I upload new apk success and waiting 24h ( time to upload: Nov 16, 2014 and current version 1.4 ). But in playstore, user install old version (1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3) not receive "Update" button ( just display Uninstall & Open button ). Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

> Once your updated app is uploaded to the Developer Console, it will
>   **take some time** for your users be notified that an update is available.
>   Users will see an Update available notification next to your app in My
>   Apps when the new version of your application is available.
>        **Please wait at least 24 hours** after publishing your app before contacting Google Play Developer Support.

source https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: I've been waiting for 26 hour. Still not Update button

Answer (score 0):

It will take some time for the play store to show your update. You should wait atleast 1 day for your update to be visible to the user.